# Что обозначает этот элемент массива?

Tags: php

```
$prim1 = array( 'a[{@№;"!""№№№"}]' )
```

Что это в скобках?Если регулярное выражение, то что оно делает?

Comment: Может и регулярное, может и нет. Мы же не видим где оно используется.

Comment: в транслитерации текста https://hello-site.ru/share/transliteraciya-teksta/

Comment: я его и выложил, чтобы вы мне объяснили

Answer (score 1):

Эта строка вообще никак не разбирается php. В данном случае (по ссылке из ваших комментариев к вопросу) данная стока используется как маркер точек, где встречалась буква `Е` или `Ё` после определенных других букв (гласных). Она используется только из того соображения, что во входном тексте точно такая же строка вряд ли когда либо появится. Ниже по тексту видно, что эту строку потом заменяют на `ye`. Таким образом достигается эффект, что слово "охАЕт" будет преобразовано в "okhAYEt" (так как Е после гласной), а слово "мЁд" в "mEd" (так как Е после согласной), а не в "mYEd".